# How do I know the message status at each step when message send using smack?

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am using ejabberd for XMPP which hosted in AWS. I am working on a chat application in android (Java). Furthermore, I used Smack 4.4.0 version (the latest version on Jan 30, 2021)

I can send and receive a message through smack in android. I can also get notification for delivered, displayed. But I could not get notification for the message sent to the server.

i.e., what I am asking is,

1. Let assume user A and user B
2. User A sends message to user B. The message will go through server. If yes, then the first receiver of user A's message is the server. If it is right, then how can I get notification for this?

E.g., : Like single tick in WhatsApp

3. If user B is in offline, then user A's message will store in the server as offline. How can I get notification for this?

E.g., : Like single tick in WhatsApp

4. User B received user A's message after coming on online. This time, the message will send by the server from an offline stored message. Where can I get notification for this?

I have searched for the above. Finally, I got [MessageEventManager](https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/xevent/MessageEventManager.html)

I have tested in my project. The displayed (Read Status) and delivered (Delivered at receiver side) are working fine. But the offline notification is not working.

And also, I could not find any reference for message received at server side i.e., single tick WhatsApp,

Because, there are no clear reference for latest version of Smack.